# Computer frozen on boot logo, cannot access BIOS with system partition attached after update to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, windows-10-upgrade

With the support for Windows 7 ending I recently updated my 5 year old desktop PC to Windows 10 using the update installer provided on the Microsoft homepage. The installation proceeded with only one minor hiccup (probably irrelevant but at the end of post), and following several reboots I was finally presented with the startup screen and the password prompt. After logging in I found everything pretty much the way I had left it and was able to use the system without issues for about a week. However thinking back I realize I only ever left the system in sleep mode and probably never completely switched it off after that first startup.

When I did switch off the PC about a week later and then restarted it I was greeted with the situation as described in the title. The ASUS logo appeared ("Inspiring Innovation - Persistent Perfection") - and stayed. What also stayed was the invitation to press DEL or F2 in order to enter the UEFI BIOS, even after I pressed those keys, and all of the others. This situation did not change on subsequent restarts even after switching keyboards, removing all other USB devices, removing the network cable, switching the keyboard to other USB ports, and finally removing all other attached hard drives except for the system drive.

After also removing the system drive the ASUS logo appeared only briefly and then a new message appeared: "The current BIOS settings do not fully support the boot device. Click OK to enter the BIOS Setup. Go to Advanced > Boot > CSM Parameters, and adjust the CSM (Compatibility Support Module) settings to enable the boot device". I did click OK (by hitting enter) and indeed finally found myself in the BIOS, went to the boot submenu and found nothing interesting there since no potential boot devices were attached.

With the motherboard exposed I noticed that the BOOT_DEVICE_LED was permanently on, indicating a problem, and decided to test what would happen with some other disks attached instead of the system drive. The LED did indeed switch off shortly after starting and instead a light blue screen appeared with a message about \WINDOWS\system32\winload.exe missing, and while I was not surprised that the file was missing - I had removed the system drive after all - it appeared that the system tried to boot from one of the hdds. Not sure what to make of that.

I have also reset the CMOS and updated the BIOS to the newest version.

I mentioned a minor hiccup that occurred during the update process that I still don't think is relevant, but it involves the system drive so I will describe it now. The problem was that the space on the system partition was a few gigabyte short of the required 8 gigabyte. Since I had split my Samsung 128gb SSD into two equal sized partitions when I first set up my system I decided to shrink the other partition and then grow the system partition by that amount. This did not work however because for whatever reason a system drive can only be merged with free space shown immediately to its right as displayed in the partition manager, and the second partition was "between" it and the free space. So I ended up deleting the second partition altogether and then merged all the free space on the disk with the system partition into one partition.

So I do not know how to proceed or if there is anything that can be done at this point. It could all be a coincidence of course and the SSD just happened to die shortly after the Windows 10 upgrade, but if that is the case why would it still be recognized as the boot device, and why would I not be able to access the BIOS as long as it is attached?

Comment: Do you have another computer to test your SSD? If yes, test it out for malfunction. A defective disk will sometimes give this exact issue. Also, did you try your PC with another HDD/SSD?

Comment: I do not have another PC available, just my laptop. There are several other HDDs in my PC, none of them block me from entering the BIOS, but there is no OS installed on them either.

Comment: First get a live USB of Linux and try installing it .You can install Linux on other HDD if your SSD is dead And if not dead then install Linux on SSD > create bootable USB from Linux > install Windows from the USB ; Recommending Linux so that you can check if your SSD is dead or not  (and since you don't have any other PC available), doing anything without knowing that would be a waste and of course there are other methods as well .So proceed as you like!!

Comment: I won't even make it into the BIOS with the SSD attached, not sure installing a new OS is even an option under these circumstances. I would like to understand how a defective drive could still be recognized as the boot device and why it would not simply be ignored.

Comment: Disable Hibernation and reboot, can you enter the bios now?

Comment: How do I disable Hibernation from the BIOS? I have no access to the OS at all. The motherboard is an ASUS M5A97 EVO R2.0 if that helps.

Comment: A little related so try them : https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/bios-not-showing-hard-drive-as-uefi-asus-m5a97-pro.401456/ & https://superuser.com/questions/1000295/why-is-my-asus-m5a97-pro-not-booting-if-i-give-it-only-the-correct-device-to-boo